# Access an array value from a JSON response using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I am new to JSON and I am having a problem accessing particular values in the JSON array that is being returned from the API call.  For instance, I would like to access the name value in the response data below (these are the first two responses from the API call).  I know I am missing something obvious but I can't quit get it.  Any help would be appreciated:

```
ReadResponse::__set_state(array(
   0 => 
  array (
    'address' => '6866 N Rochester Rd',
    'category' => 'Food & Beverage > Restaurants',
    'category_ids' => 
    array (
      0 => 347,
    ),
    'category_labels' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Social',
        1 => 'Food and Dining',
        2 => 'Restaurants',
      ),
    ),
    'country' => 'us',
    'factual_id' => '8e6aacfa-b435-407d-83f9-90cec16c1cf8',
    'latitude' => 42.69804075,
    'locality' => 'Rochester Hills',
    'longitude' => -83.134586375,
    'name' => 'Sushi Little Tokyo',
    'neighborhood' => 
    array (
      0 => '\\Livernois-Tienken\\',
    ),
    'postcode' => '48306',
    'region' => 'MI',
    'status' => '1',
    'tel' => '(248) 608-1260',
  ),
   1 => 
  array (
    'address' => '2964 S Rochester Rd',
    'category' => 'Food & Beverage > Restaurants',
    'category_ids' => 
    array (
      0 => 347,
    ),
    'category_labels' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Social',
        1 => 'Food and Dining',
        2 => 'Restaurants',
      ),
    ),
    'country' => 'us',
    'factual_id' => '35d2fc06-a941-4dbf-9dcb-204964fec730',
    'latitude' => 42.636786765426,
    'locality' => 'Rochester Hills',
    'longitude' => -83.131888674506,
    'name' => 'Pudthi and Sushi',
    'postcode' => '48307',
    'region' => 'MI',
    'status' => '1',
    'tel' => '(248) 299-6890',
    'website' => 'http://www.pudthaiandsushi.com',
  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this PHP function `json_decode()` to translate your JSON response into a PHP multidimensional array where you can easily access the values in the array like
the name would be

```
$name = $myPHPArray->country->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of a var_export. The data is all contained in an instance of the `ReadResponse`. To find out how you can access the data, read the source or documentation of that class.